# Opera doesn't recognise my event handler bound to a form's "submit" event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, opera, onsubmit

Edit: This question is silly, as I had a mistake somewhere else that led to it.

I decided I'd test out my site on Opera today seeing that it works perfectly in Chrome and FF.. So I downloaded the latest Opera for Ubuntu and tried to log into my site. BLEH.

For some reason it is not recognising any functions I bind to the "submit" event of forms, which I need for validation etc.  I have the usual `addEvent(element, eventtype, callback)` which performs the relevant call to either `addEventListener` or `attachEvent`.

As I said, this works perfectly in both Chrome and Firefox.  I even tried

```
addEvent(loginForm, 'submit', function(){alert("It works");});
```

but had no response at all.  So it's not even about stopping the default action as I'd first thought, but doesn't actually bind the event at all!  With regard to the above example, I can confirm that `loginForm` does contain a reference to the actual form element.

Does anybody have any idea what is going on with Opera?

EDIT: Below is my `addEvent` function

```
function addEvent (obj, evt, callback) {
    if (evt=="mousewheel")
        evt = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel"
    if (obj.addEventListener){
        obj.addEventListener(evt, callback, false);
    } else {
        obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, callback);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are dozens of variations of addEvent from a similar number of coders.  You'll need to post your version, or at least specify where you're picking it up from.

I expect the issue is that whatever flavor you're using has some sort of issue... but it can't be debugged without know what flavor that is.  Plus, what is 'loginForm'?  Is that an attempt to use the expando'd version of document.getElementById('loginForm')?  Antiquated (and problematic) syntax if so.

Comment: Have you tried putting return false; some browser just submit it if the function return true;

Comment: @John: Posted my addEvent function.  loginForm is just a variable containing the result of a getElementById() call.

@ysrb: I'm more concerned that the callbacks aren't even being called.

Comment: more specifically, as I mentioned in the post, it contains a reference to the form element.

Comment: Okay.. what is one supposed to do when they realise there question was a mistake in thebeginning :-/  I found a big booboo.  I didn't realise I had an intermediary function that checked if the object was an array or NodeList, and would then individually pass the objects for event binding.  So I had a duck-typing failure now :-/  Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Here goes another shameless framework plug...

```
YAHOO.Util.Event.on( loginForm, 'click', function(e){
    alert('It definitely works now!');
} );
```

Idk if you're keen on adding a bit of YUI/jquery or not :D

Comment: @-1, And exactly what is wrong with normalising browser events?

Comment: Hey man.  Thanks, but I'm not using any frameworks - sticking to raw JS.  (not sure why you got a -1 ) wasn't me :P

Comment: No worries, thought I'd suggest it in case :)

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code, see below:

```
window.onload = function(){

    var loginForm = document.getElementById("frm");

    function addEvent (obj, evt, callback) {
        if (evt=="mousewheel") {
            evt = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel"
        }
        if (obj.addEventListener){
            obj.addEventListener(evt, callback, false);
        } else {
            obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, callback);
        }
    }

    addEvent(loginForm, 'submit', function(){alert("It works");});
}
```

And it works. Although I'm currently on a PC in Opera.

Have you tried using Dragonfly to see if there is any errors?

Comment: Hey thanks.. Unfortunately, it was a mistake somewhere else where I'd used duck-typing to identify whether an object was some array-type object.  This allowed me to pass arrays (or node-lists) to my addEvent and let it handle each array-item individually.  But my duck-typing failed in opera, who thought my form was an array haha.. :(
Thank you though.

Comment: Interesting.. Why didn't other browsers also believe your form was an array, then?